# How to get count(*) on PHP?

Tags: php

I have a following outputs from MySQL.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 19
        [date] => 2010-10-04 11:00:00
        [course] => Yoga
        [course_id] => 19
        [count(*)] => 2
        [capacity] => 20
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 20
        [date] => 2010-10-04 13:00:00
        [course] => Spin
        [course_id] => 20
        [count(*)] => 1
        [capacity] => 24
    )
...
...
```

I can get date, course etc, but I am not sure how to get count(*) with PHP.

```
foreach ($bookingnum as $key => $list){
    echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$list->date."</td>\n";
            echo "<td align='center'>".$list->course."</td>\n";
          //  echo "<td align='center'>".$list->count(*)."</td>\n";
         // this is wrong. how to get count(*)?? 
 ....
 ...
```

Comment: OT: `echo $list->course` should be  `echo htmlspecialchars($list->course)`

Comment: OT: @pomeL how would you know ? Maybe his results already has Entities ...

Comment: Or he may not need them, maybe not using X(HT)ML. I does ever use Entities, thinks that it destroys the beauty of my language.

Answer (score 16):

Modify your base query as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` ...
```

then you can use this as

```
$list->total
```

Comment: simple but brilliant +1 from me

Answer (score 9):

Ha, weird Situation you have there... Okay, since obviously `count(*)` is not a valid Attribute name you can do 3 things that come to mind:

1. use `$list->{"count(*)"}`
2. change the mysql query to `count(*) as count` and then use `$list->count`
3. change request mode so you get an array as result instead of an stdClass Object

Answer (score 1):

```
$total = count($bookingnum);
foreach ($bookingnum as $key => $list){
    echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$list->date."</td>\n";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$list->course."</td>\n";
    echo "<td align='center'>".$total."</td>\n";
}
```

ops! my fault, wrong answer, i catched the point when i saw fabrik answer +1 to him

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently get properties with weird names like `$list->{'count(*)'}`.  But ideally, you'll want to change the query.  Give the count an alias, like `SELECT ... COUNT(*) cnt ...`, as it'll be easier to work with.  Then you can get `$list->cnt` instead of resorting to weird syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
If you are doing a pagination and want to figure out the total number of records available, you might want to adjust your query with `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ..` and after your main query is sent , send another query

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total_records
```

However keep in mind `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` has performance implications.

Edit:
Just realized i just got the question wrong, really silly answer.. taking the first part back :)

Comment: the count attribute of each result does clearly not represent the count of results itself

Comment: oh, now i understand the question. You already have count(*) in the query and just want to access it in ur dataset, in that case the simplest way is to just do SELECT blah, blah , count(*) as num_recs FROM ....